# CSS inline UTF-encoded SVG - 404 error in Safari 8.0.3

Tags: css, svg

In a CSS document, I have used a UTF-encoded SVG snippet for a background image like so:

```
body {
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16"><circle fill="#529ECC" cx="8" cy="8" r="1"/></svg>');
}
```

The SVG image displays fine, however, In Safari 8.0.3 I'm receiving a console error -

```
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`
```

Here's a [jsbin demo](http://jsbin.com/fadihu) - the console error only shows on the live preview not in the edit page (click arrow icon above output panel).

Why is there a 404 error (this is not a URL request but a data string?), and is there a way to prevent it?

**Update**: I've included URL-encoded versions in the JSBin, doesn't fix it. Base64 encode does stop the error but I want to use UTF as per [this](http://css-tricks.com/probably-dont-base64-svg/) article.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of the data url is incorrect, it must be url encoded (or base64 encoded).

For instance # is illegal, url encoding would convert it to %23

Comment: Thx, I tried base64 encoding and it stops the error. However, according to this article http://css-tricks.com/probably-dont-base64-svg/ it's safe and marginally preferable to encode CSS SVGs as UTF. So I'm curious if this is just a Safari bug?

Comment: @MachineElf Any browser that *doesn't* break on the `#` character is a bug (currently Chrome/Opera are the only ones that allow it).  You should always URL-encode the `#` if you want it to be part of the URL and not the start of a target fragment.  For IE in particular, you also need to encode the entire string (whitespace and angle brackets). Whether to use URL-encoding or base-64 encoding is more of an open debate; base-64 is initially shorter, but URL encoding might be smaller after gzip compression because there are lots of repeated sequences.

Comment: Thx again, I've tried URL-encoding all and some of the UTF string (eg # chara), but can't get the 404 error to stop. You can see the results here - http://jsbin.com/fadihu/8/edit?css,output - the Safari 8 console error shows in the live preview (arrow button above output panel).

Comment: Presumably a Safari bug, report it to the webkit bug tracker unless they already know about it: https://bugs.webkit.org/